# Strange sequence classification performance after shuffling sequence elements

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I have one million sequences I'm trying to classify as either 0 or 1. The outcome is fairly well balanced (class 0:70%, class 1:30%). Maximum sequence length is 50, and I've post-padded by sequences with zeroes. There are 100 unique sequence symbols. Embedding length is 30. It's an LSTM NN trained on two outputs (one is the main output node, and the other is right after the LSTM). The code is below.

As a sanity check, I ran three versions of this: One in which I randomize the outcome labels (I expect terrible performance), another one where the labels are correct but I randomize the sequence of events in each sequence but the outcome labels are correct (I also expected bad performance), and finally one where everything is left unshuffled (I expected good performance).

Instead I found the following:

- Shuffled labels: Accuracy = 69.5% (Model predicts every sequence is class 0)
- Shuffled sequence symbols: Accuracy = 88%!
- Nothing is shuffled: Accuracy = 90%

What do you make of this? All I can think of is that there is little signal to be gained from analyzing the sequences, and maybe most of the signal is from the presence or lack of presence of symbols in the sequence. Maybe RNNs and LSTMs are overkill here?

```py
# Input 1: event type sequences
# Take the event integer sequences, run them through an embedding layer to get float vectors, then run through LSTM
main_input = Input(shape =(max_seq_length,), dtype = 'int32', name = 'main_input')
x = Embedding(output_dim = embedding_length, input_dim = num_unique_event_symbols, input_length = max_seq_length, mask_zero=True)(main_input)
lstm_out = LSTM(32)(x)

# Auxiliary loss here from first input
auxiliary_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(lstm_out)

# An abitrary number of dense, hidden layers here
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(lstm_out)

# The main output node
main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

## Compile and fit the model
model = Model(inputs=[main_input], outputs=[main_output, auxiliary_output])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], loss_weights=[1., 0.2])
print(model.summary())
np.random.seed(21)
model.fit([train_X1], [train_Y, train_Y], epochs=1, batch_size=200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've played around with the size of the LSTM, your conclusion seems reasonable. Beyond that, it's hard to say as it depends what the dataset is. For example, it could be that shorter sequences are more unpredictable, and if most of your sequences are short, then this would support the conclusion as well.

It's worth it to also try truncating your sequences in length, to say the first 25 entries.

Comment: That's an interesting idea about sequence length. I'll explore that a bit. Thanks!